Change of Limit in Calculation of Mean
This video here  has
$CDF=F(x)=\text{sin } x, 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$
which gives on differentiating:
$$PDF=f(x)=\text{cos } x, 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
But then when calculating the mean is there a reason to change the limits of integration, or is it a mistake?
$$\int_{0}^{1} x \text{ cos }x \text{ }dx$$

Without having looked at the video, this looks like a mistake.
